# Modelling a two-way relationship using one row with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say that I have a MySQL table that I wish to use to use to model a relationship between two entities (A and B, for example). There are three columns: Person1, Person2, and Relationship. Let's further say that A and B are persons in this table and could have one of several relationship types, such as being friends, one requesting the other to be a friend, and so forth.

Is it possible (and preferable?) to use one row to do this? It seems like having one row that represents the A->B part of the relationship and *another* for the B->A part of the relationship would be a somewhat fragile setup, since if either of the two ever neglects to be updated the model could be in a rather odd state (A thinks B is a friend, B thinks A is something else).

The other part of my question is: how would efficient look-ups work? If there was only one row to represent the relationship, wouldn't all queries need to do a SELECT to check whether it is in the Person1 field *or* the Person2 field? Is there a nicer way of modelling this type of data?

(I realize this explanation is a little rough; please let me know if you'd like any clarification.)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a column for the person who requested the relationship, the "requestee", the type of relationship (friend, etc), and whether the relationship has been approved by the "requestee"

Comment: True, but what happens after the request turns into a pair of confirmed friends? The direction shouldn't matter, and both people should be able to easily discern if that are a part of that relationship.

Comment: It wouldn't matter.... something like this would get you all the relationships you are in that are confirmed.. SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE (requester = myid OR requestee = myid) AND approved = 1

Comment: In my last paragraph, I was asking about whether there is a way to avoid having OR checks in all of my queries. If this was the case, I couldn't index on any particular column, since both Person1 and Person2 would always need to be checked.